# Visual Studio QT - How can I generate a .pro file?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using VS2019 for a QT project, problem is that I'd also like it to work on this project with QT creator, for that I assume I'd also need the .pro file, right? How do I make visual studio create this file?

Comment: [Qt:Where to find the .pro file when developing with visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62688364/qtwhere-to-find-the-pro-file-when-developing-with-visual-studio)